# Codec mismatch on setting write format to slin from alaw native formats (alaw)

Tags: asterisk, codec, ivr

I am facing the issue on asterisk 13 that calls go silent on some channels and show warning,

[Mar 18 09:00:22] WARNING[32642][C-00004cd6] channel.c: Codec mismatch on channel DAHDI/118-1 setting write format to slin from alaw native formats (alaw)

[Mar 18 09:09:02] WARNING[25844][C-00004a06] channel.c: Codec mismatch on channel DAHDI/151-1 setting write format to slin from alaw native formats (alaw)

If any idea regarding this, Please explain how can i resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
asterisk -rx "core show translation"
```

That will show you codecs. If alaw to slin path is present(99.9% chance), then issues is DAHDI config.

Comment: Yes Its present, can you please tell what could be wrong with Dahdi Config?

Comment: Can be anything. Framing/coding not same on different channels, card broken etc.

Comment: So, how to configure it for DAHDI? @arheops

Comment: you should not. Search elsewhere. In pjsip, codecs etc